# MySQL Closest Match Using ABS confusion

Tags: php, mysql, tabs, sql-order-by, match

Very Simple one, just stumped on syntax and not finding a good example anywhere.

I want to search for the closest match in a database. Earlier on the page I define $rating, and that is the value I want to match to.  Uploaderating is the value I want to match to within the table.

I am using the following:

```
$SQL = "SELECT TOP(1) id
FROM table
WHERE uploader != '$username'
ORDER BY ABS(uploaderrating - $rating)";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row1= mysql_fetch_array($result);
$id1 = $row1[id];
```

Instead of getting the row ID which is what I want, I get the following:

mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in mysite at row number.

Comment: The terms of MySQL and SQL are very different. You need to be as accurate as possible, as SQL and MySQL contain different functions etc by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the TOP function exist in your install my MySQL?

Try this syntax:

```
SELECT id
FROM test
WHERE uploader != '$username'
ORDER BY ABS(uploaderrating - $rating)
LIMIT 0,1
```

Demo can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b42f0/5).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mysql you have to use

```
SELECT id
...
limit 1
```